# Is it possible to measure packet rate with libpcap?

Tags: python, pcap, libpcap

I have a python script, that uses libpcap (pcapy) to capture some specific packets, for example, packets from 10.1.1.1 to 10.2.2.2. Is it possible to measure that data transfer rate? I mean, we can get a size of packet, but as I understand, we can't find out how long did it take to transfer that packet. Is there some another way to measure packet rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`time`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html) to time how long it takes to get the packet:

```
import time
start = time.time()
# do something you want to time
elapsed = time.time() - start
```

Comment: How do you identify (1) the time when the packet X leaves 10.1.1.1 and (2) the time when the packet X arrives at 10.2.2.2?